# Checking and infilling the central pixel with 8 pixel neighbourhood mode in a large array in Python

Tags: python, interpolation, python-xarray

I have a big binary array `(500 x 700)` in which I want to check '`NaNs`' and infill the central pixel with the mode of eight surrounding pixels (if more than 4 surrounding pixels have 0 or 1). It's more like a 3x3 sliding window search. Are there any tools/functions to do this in either xarray or scipy.ndimage or even numpy?

Eg.

```
arr = np.asarray([0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1, 1, np.nan, 0,  1,  0,  1, 1,  1,  0,  1,  1, np.nan]).reshape(3,6)

arr[1,1] = 1 
arr[-1,-1] = 1 (only 3 neighbours)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you be a little more precise as to what you want to do exactly ? If I understood correctly, you want to replace NaNs (and only NaNs), with the average of the surrounding of the 8 pixels ? Does your array contain only 0, 1 and NaN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement your idea directly using numpy and `scipy.stats.mode`.

First, find locations of nan values by comparing an array to itself because a NaN float is not equal to itself by definition. The `np.where` function will return all locations this condition holds, in two tuples of indices, one for the rows and the other for columns.

Then, for each location where a NaN is found, add 8 deltas to it to get its surrounding pixels. This can be done efficiently using a delta array, which lists all possible offsets for the row and column index, for each neighbour.

Finally, do a within-boundary check and run the `mode` function on the selected, valid neighbours and fill this value into the NaN cell.

Here's the code following my description above:

```py
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats

arr = np.asarray([
    0,  1,  1,  1,  0,  1,
    1, np.nan, 0,  1,  0,  1,
    1,  1,  0,  1,  1, np.nan
]).reshape(3, 6)

delta_rows = np.array([-1, -1, -1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1])
delta_cols = np.array([-1, 0, 1, -1, 1, -1, 0, 1])
nan_rows, nan_cols = np.where(arr != arr)
for nan_row, nan_col in zip(nan_rows, nan_cols):
    neighbour_rows = nan_row + delta_rows
    neighbour_cols = nan_col + delta_cols
    within_boundary = (
        (0 <= neighbour_rows) & (neighbour_rows < arr.shape[0]) & 
        (0 <= neighbour_cols) & (neighbour_cols < arr.shape[1])
    )
    neighbour_rows = neighbour_rows[within_boundary]
    neighbour_cols = neighbour_cols[within_boundary]
    arr[nan_row, nan_col] = scipy.stats.mode(arr[neighbour_rows, neighbour_cols]).mode
```

Afterwards, we can see that each NaN value in `arr` is correctly populated with the mode of its surrounding cells:

```py
>>> print(arr)
[[0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: Thanks that solved it. I will try this for the array time-series and will revert if it doesn't work well. Much appreciated.